# printing the same field of next record after a match in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to get the exact field of the next record after a match, for example, if "string1" is matched in $2 then i need to get the value of $2 of next record. i have around 100 such strings to match each occurring exactly once in an input file. but the same search string can be present in a different input file (i have more than 1000 such input files).

sample input: comma separated

```
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Radio / AMR Configuration Slot02,
RX RF Frequency Slot02,Channel Spacing Slot02,AMR Range (QPSK) Slot02,AMR Range (16QAM) Slot02
37740.500 [MHz],7 [MHz],Enable,Enable
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Radio / AMR Configuration Slot03,
RX RF Frequency (Slot03),Channel Spacing (Slot03),AMR Range (QPSK) {(Slot03)|(SW GRP2)},AMR Range (16QAM) {(Slot03)|(SW GRP2)}
37712.500 [MHz],7 [MHz],Enable,Enable
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Radio / AMR Configuration Slot04,
RX RF Frequency Slot04,Channel Spacing Slot04,AMR Range (QPSK) Slot04,AMR Range (16QAM) Slot04
,,,
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Radio / AMR Configuration Slot05,
RX RF Frequency (Slot05),Channel Spacing (Slot05),AMR Range (QPSK) {(Slot05)|(SW GRP3)},AMR Range (16QAM) {(Slot05)|(SW GRP3)}
```

string1,string2....are search patterns contains alphanumeric with ({| in between.
value fields can be empty.
number of fields is not fixed.
the location of string1 is not fixed. may occur in different position but will only occur once in a file.

what i tried so far:

```
BEGIN {
FS=OFS=","
}
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
if ($i == "string1"){
    getline val;
    split(val,a,",");
    am1=a[i]}
if ($i == "string2"){
    getline val;
    split(val,a,",");
    am2=a[i]}
}
}
END {print am1,am2}
```

i know that this doesn't work for the given input since the i gets changed for consecutive value1 and value2. should i use different for loop for every single search string? or suggest any solution please.

for search

```
string1="AMR Range (QPSK) Slot02",string2="AMR Range (QPSK) {(Slot03)|(SW GRP2)}",string3="AMR Range (QPSK) Slot04",string4="AMR Range (16QAM) Slot02"
```

Desired output:

```
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Enable,Enable,,Enable
```

Comment: Where is your other input file, what does it look like and what is it called?

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (both input files and replace all the `blah`s, `string`s, and `value`s with meaningful representative values) and the expected output given that input. If you're ever considering using `getline` be sure to first read and fully understand all the implications and caveats at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Comment: @MarkSetchell other input files are same format only the search string positions are different.

Comment: @Ed Morton I have changed the input and output data. I first tried to use getline without variable format and realized the hard way that should have avoided it. After going through this document i found that getline variable format is much safer. I have already considered your solution to print the nth record after match '!--c;/pattern/{c=N}' file but couldn't figure out how to get the specific field. I still don't understand getline and its caveats so any solution without getline is ok. If I can get the solution for one file, then i will be able to apply the script on multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your output format but perhaps this will help. This creates the mapping of search keywords to values in the corresponding next line

Changed your last input line

```
$ cat file
blah,blah,blah,string1,string2,string3,blah
blah,blah,blah,value1,value2,value3,blah
string4,blah,string5,string6,blah
value4,x,value5,value6,x
```

and create a separate lookup file

```
$ cat lookup
string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
string6
```

and finally the script

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{m[$0];next} 
            FNR==1{p=$0;next}
                  {n=split(p,a); 
                   for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if(a[i] in m) print a[i],$i; 
                   p=$0}' lookup file
```

generates output

```
string1 value1
string2 value2
string3 value3
string4 value4
string5 value5
string6 value6
```

you can run the same script with multiple data files as well

```
$ awk ... lookup file1 file2 file3 ...
```

and perhaps add FILENAME in the print to identify which file was the source of the matches.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ever considering using `getline` be sure to first read and fully understand all the implications and caveats at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

I don't understand how you get the posted expected output from the posted sample input but given this input:

```
$ cat strings
AMR Range (QPSK) Slot02
AMR Range (QPSK) {(Slot03)|(SW GRP2)}
AMR Range (QPSK) Slot04
AMR Range (16QAM) Slot02

$ cat file
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Radio / AMR Configuration Slot02,
RX RF Frequency Slot02,Channel Spacing Slot02,AMR Range (QPSK) Slot02,AMR Range (16QAM) Slot02
37740.500 [MHz],7 [MHz],Enable,Enable
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Radio / AMR Configuration Slot03,
RX RF Frequency (Slot03),Channel Spacing (Slot03),AMR Range (QPSK) {(Slot03)|(SW GRP2)},AMR Range (16QAM) {(Slot03)|(SW GRP2)}
37712.500 [MHz],7 [MHz],Enable,Enable
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Radio / AMR Configuration Slot04,
RX RF Frequency Slot04,Channel Spacing Slot04,AMR Range (QPSK) Slot04,AMR Range (16QAM) Slot04
,,,
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Radio / AMR Configuration Slot05,
RX RF Frequency (Slot05),Channel Spacing (Slot05),AMR Range (QPSK) {(Slot05)|(SW GRP3)},AMR Range (16QAM) {(Slot05)|(SW GRP3)}
```

I think the following does what you describe in the text:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { strings[$0]; next }
FNR==1 { out = $1 OFS $2 }
{
    if (pos) {
        out = out OFS $pos
        pos = 0
    }
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in strings) {
            pos = i
        }
    }
}
ENDFILE {
    if (pos) {
        out = out OFS $pos
        pos = 0
    }
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk strings file
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Enable,Enable,
```

The above uses GNU awk for ENDFILE instead of END so you can do:

```
awk -f tst.awk strings file1 file2 ....
```

or similar to handle multiple files simultaneously.

If your strings have to be hard-coded in your awk script then it's just a tweak to:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    split("AMR Range (QPSK) Slot02\n\
AMR Range (QPSK) {(Slot03)|(SW GRP2)}\n\
AMR Range (QPSK) Slot04\n\
AMR Range (16QAM) Slot02", tmp, /\n/)
    for (i in tmp) {
        strings[tmp[i]]
    }
}
FNR==1 { out = $1 OFS $2 }
{
    if (pos) {
        out = out OFS $pos
        pos = 0
    }
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in strings) {
            pos = i
        }
    }
}
ENDFILE {
    if (pos) {
        out = out OFS $pos
        pos = 0
    }
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
10.217.250.162,NTTN_EMS,Enable,Enable,
```

Comment: two issues to clear 1. search strings are not stored in a different file and cannot be supplied as input. 2. the position of the search strings vary from file to file so it cannot be known beforehand. that means the position of the match must be known from the data file itself.

Comment: Telling us where the search strings are NOT stored is useful but telling us where they ARE stored would be significantly MORE useful. Individual shell variables? A shell array? Hard-coded in awk? Something else? Also, the script makes no assumptions about the position of the search strings - it just finds them and records the position it found them in for use on the subsequent line.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a version with the strings hard-coded in the script in case that's what you're looking for.

Comment: the output for 4th string is missing in the output. the value it should return given the input is "Enable"

Comment: And where would it get that from? Unlike all of the other cases, there is no line after the line which contains the final matching string and you've provided no requirement other than to get the field from the subsequent line. Either you have an additional requirement you haven't told us about, or you provided incomplete input, or I'm missing something.

Comment: the 4th string is in record 2: $4, the value "Enable" is in the subsequent line record 3: $4. I have applied this script to other set of inputs and found out that when two search strings are positioned in consecutive fields of the same record, only the first string's output is printed. for example, if two strings are positioned in say $3 and $4 of record 2, the $3 of record 3 is printed and $4 of record 3 gets omitted.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. Maybe someone else can figure it out. Good luck!

Comment: Ed, this is definitely necro-posting but I think that adding your comment about using `getline` in Awk along with the link to your original _comp.lang.awk_ post (or [wherever](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.awk/msg/66b5bf127ae4d443) it can still be found) _inside_ your solution would alone justify upvotes. It's a really useful reference and obviously a labor of love very much worth passing on.

Comment: @Cbhihe OK, I added it. If you had something else in mind please feel free to edit my answer.